# How to use ngFor to iterate over array of objects

Tags: html, json, angular

I am trying to use an ngFor directive iterating over a component attribute.
my top level component is

```
export class OverviewComponent {
    public mips : Array<Object> =  [
    {id: '44',  label: 'MIPS 44',   description: 'Preoperative Beta Blocker'},
    {id: '76',  label: 'MIPS 76',   description: 'Central Line : Sterility'},
    {id: '404', label: 'MIPS 404',  description: 'Smoking Abstinence'},
    {id: '424', label: 'MIPS 424',  description: 'Perioperative Temperature Management'},
    {id: '430', label: 'MIPS 430',  description: 'PONV Adult'},
    {id: '463', label: 'MIPS 463',  description: 'PONV Pediatrics'},
];
...
}
```

in my top level component html, I have

```
<pie-chart class="mips-details"
           *ngFor="let mip of mips"
           summary="true"
           details={{mip}}>
</pie-chart>
```

My pie component has an input parameter such as

```
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input()
    details : any;
```

What I am having problem with is how to set the details input.
The way I have it setup, when I look at this.details, it shows '[object object]'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the code for piechartcomponent html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are passing data to the child using **`@input`**, the binding should be as,

```
<pie-chart class="mips-details"
           *ngFor="let mip of mips"
           summary="true"
           [details]=mip>
</pie-chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [the following syntax](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) to bind the `details` property:

```
[details]="mip"
```